# Свойство css3 transform3d

Tags: css3

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, как правильно использовать свойство? Хочу повернуть блок по оси X на 80 градусов. И еще вопрос - можно ли повернуть только фон? Чтобы содержимое осталось нетронутым.

Answer (score 1):

Смотри пример [transform](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transform). Можно сделать 2 блока. Фон через блок-абсолют относительно вашего содержимого и ему провести трансформацию.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform: rotateX(80deg);
```

Что там про фон?

Comment: Про фон, что надо только фон повернуть. Какое обратное преобразование?

Comment: @Qwertiy тоесть Вам нужно повернуть background? Я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: Ну если не считать, что это нужно не мне, то, вероятно, да. Как обратить преобразование по аналогии с 2D? http://jsfiddle.net/jeocn1hb/

Comment: Так Вам нужно в 2D или же в 3D?

Comment: 1. Ещё раз, нужно не мне. Не я вопрос задал. 2. Восстановил свою попытку ответа - обратное преобразование в ней неверно. 3. 2D - это пример стандартного решения - преобразовать для родителя, а для потомка сделать обратное преобразование. 4. В вопросе говорится о 3D. 5. Вероятно, матрица в вотпросе не случайно - обратную матрицу, вероятно, можно вычислить.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
  transform: rotateX(80deg);
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background: silver;
  line-height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  transform: rotateX(-80deg);
}
```

```html
<div class=outer><div class=inner>Contents</div></div>
```

UPDATE: Я не прав, это не отмена.